# Magento 1.9: One grouped (or bundle-) product with two different tax classes

Tags: php, magento

I've searched quite long time around for that problem. Since I cannot find any answer, I want to post it here and hope I'm not the only one with that problem.

So here's the thing:

In Germany we have two different tax classes (both appear in the Shop):

- 7% discounted products (like food) --> product A (example: 20 EUR)
- 19% all other products --> product B (example: 10 EUR)

Now I want to add a new grouped (or bundle-) product, which should contain both products, but it should cost less. So taking this example, it should look like:

Product C contains then:

- product A --> with discounted price: 15 EUR
- product B --> with discounted price: 9 EUR

So in the cart is should be appear like:

---

Subtotal:   22,00 EUR

Tax (7%):    1,07 EUR (15 * 7%)

Tax (19%):   1,71 EUR (9 * 19%)

Total (with tax): 24,78 EUR

---

I'm aware of that the calculation, of course, depends on the discount for each product. I'm just wondering if there is a solution either out of the box of magento or with any extension, that should be easy to handle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is on the usage of Magento or to find a extension for Magento and not in anyway an attempt to develop on Magento. You question may be best suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @b.enoit.be  In a way you're right. I should have added, that if there is no way to use a out-of-the-box solution, I would develop something by myself. But if somebody had a similar problem in the past, I would be glad if the experience is shared in the community. So the answer to my post can be a development-like solution as well.

Comment: Well if you actually "just" plan to develop something yourself, then your question is too broad. We are not going to develop a full blown module for you. Stackoveflow is a Q&A for specific programmation question and / or problems. In that essence, your question, as it is right now, doesn't fit those criteria.